# SQL Statement Not Selecting

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server in a C# project for a troubleshooting program and I have a table that contains ID,Question,QuestionId,Solution and Rank. I want there to be multiple solutions to a problem and the program will choose the best ranked solution, which is just chosen by the highest number which gets incremented every time it is correct. For this I have the following SQL statement:

```
sql = "SELECT Solution FROM dbo.Questions WHERE Rank=(SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM 
dbo.Questions) AND QuestionId =" + questionId;
```

When I had just one solution available this worked fine, but when I have multiple solutions it doesn't.

Comment: `SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM 
dbo.VideoPlayer` returns the max of *all* `QuestionIds` so if it then does not match the rank of the specific questionId you look for you get no rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to properly parameterize your queries. [Bobby Tables: A guide to preventing SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

```
sql = "SELECT Solution FROM dbo.Questions q WHERE Rank=(SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM 
dbo.Questions i where i.QuestionId = q.QuestionId) AND q.QuestionId =" + questionId;
```

This makes sure the `max(rank)` returned by the subquery is the `max(rank)` of the solution for the `QuestionId` you are querying for.

You can also do this if you just want one `Solution`:

```
select top 1 Solution 
from dbo.Questions q 
where QuestionId = @QuestionId
order by [Rank] desc
```

Answer (score 4):

You're selecting the max rank of *all* solutions and looking for the solution to a specified question with that rank.

Start at the beginning - select the possible solutions into a CTE

```
with solutions as(
   SELECT Solution, Rank FROM dbo.Questions WHERE QuestionId = @questionId
)
... more to come
```

Given that, you can use a [ranking function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx) to rank all the possible solutions, by rank and select the one with the best rank (too many ranks in that sentence!)

```
with solutions as(
   SELECT Solution, Rank() OVER (ORDER BY Rank DESC) as rank 
   FROM dbo.Questions WHERE QuestionId = @questionId
)
SELECT * FROM solutions WHERE rank = 1
```

This doesnt cover 2 solutions having an equal rank - you'll get 2 results from the query if 2 have the same rank. Two solutions there - consider using both.

1. Chose a tiebreaker column - perhaps the most recent - by adding a second column into the `ORDER BY` (`...RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rank DESC, CreatedDate DESC`)
2. Throw a `TOP 1` into the final select (`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM solutions WHERE rank = 1`)

Answer (score 0):

The record has the MAX rank may not have the questionId you given in the  AND QuestionId =" + questionId;

Answer (score 0):

You might try this, I have left the where clause outside of the CTE query so that you can also use the query to get a complete list of each question with it's max rank (if you leave out the questionId filter):

```
    with [ctreMaxSolution] as
    (
        select  [QuestionId]
              , max([Rank]) as [Rank]
        from    [dbo].[Questions]
        group by [QuestionId]
    )
    select  *
    from    [dbo].[Questions] as [q]
            inner join [cteMaxSolution] as [cms] on [q].[QuestionId] = [cms].[QuestionId]
                                                and [q].[Rank] = [cms].[Rank]
    where [q].[QuestionId] = @questionId;
```

I've used a SQL Server variable there, but you can make a stored procedure out of it or convert it to an ad-hoc query like in your question, totally up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First make a filter by "questionId" and then "order By" rank.

try with this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 q.solution FROM dbo.Questions q WHERE q.QuestionId = @QuestionId
ORDER BY q.Rank desc
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score -2):

Kindly modify your query as below.

```
sql = "SELECT Solution FROM dbo.Questions WHERE Rank in (SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM 
dbo.Questions) AND QuestionId =" + questionId;
```

Here i have modified where rank "in" instead of "="

Comment: This will still select the max rank of all possible questions!

Comment: I can't reasonably justify an upvote on grounds that it not only doesn't answer the question, but also still enforces dangerous SQL practices...