# SQL - Syntax Error When Trying to Increment a Value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server in a C# project for a troubleshooting program and I have a table that contains ID,Question,QuestionId,Solution and Rank. [I previously asked a question and it worked for selecting, so I tried modifying that for an Update instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976438/sql-statement-not-selecting) I'm trying to increment the rank of the solution with the highest rank by 1.

```
sql = "UPDATE dbo.Questions SET Rank = Rank + 1 q WHERE Rank=(SELECT MAX(Rank) FROM dbo.Questions i where i.QuestionId = q.QuestionId) AND q.QuestionId = " + questionId;
```

I get the following error with this:

> Incorrect syntax near 'q'
>     Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'

Comment: `UPDATE dbo.Questions q SET ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table alias is in the wrong place.  In SQL Server, you want a `FROM` clause:

```
UPDATE q
    SET Rank = Rank + 1
    FROM dbo.Questions q
    WHERE Rank = (SELECT MAX(Rank)
                  FROM dbo.Questions i 
                  WHERE i.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
                 ) AND
         q.QuestionId = " + questionId;
```

You can also write this as:

```
UPDATE q
    SET Rank = Rank + 1
    FROM (SELECT TOP (1) q.*
          FROM dbo.Questions q
          WHERE q.QuestionId = " + questionId
          ORDER BY rank DESC
         );
```

This makes it obvious that you only want to update one row.

Let me also add . . . learn to use query parameters.  Don't put `questionId` directly into the query string.  That is just a way to introduce syntax errors that are really hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I'll have to look into using query parameters.

Comment: "This is just a way to introduce syntax errors...." Yep! It's also what SQL injection attacks rely on.